# Visual Studio 2017 duplicate install

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 Professional on Windows 10. Then using the installer I saw that VS 2017 Enterprise was "available" so I installed it. Now all of VS (Blend, VS, etc.) are duplicated in the start menu. I would like to be able to remove the duplicate entries in the start menu but I don't seem to have that option. Does anyone know how to remove all of the "...(2)" entries in the start menu? And related why does VS installer create these duplicate entries?

Comment: just go to setting and uninstall what you don't need

Comment: What shows as installed is Visual Studio 2017. I obviously don't want to uninstall that. What shows up on the start menu is a bunch of entries suffixed by '(2)'. It is those entries on the start menu that I want to remove not uninstall VS. For example on the start menu I see 'Visual Studio 2017' AND 'Visual Studio 2017 (2)'. On the list of programs available to uninstall I only see 'Visual Studio 2017'.

Comment: then just remove from start menu

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. Hence the question. This is not the "Start Menu" (although Windows calls it "Start"). This is the Start that is selected from the far left hand of the tool bar at the bottom of the screen, For me it shows an alphabetical list of applications on the left and a set of tiles on the right for selected applications. It is the alphabetical list where the VS items are duplicated.

Comment: look at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Comment: Thank you. That is just the tip I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the duplicate item in the start menu > more > go to file location. There will be shortcuts titled the same as the items on your start menu, just delete the shortcuts and your start menu will reflect instantly.

Or goto :
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

and remove them directly